# Can I transfer purchased content from an iPhone to an authorised PC

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, data-transfer

Ok so on *computer 1*, I have setup my iPhone, authorised *computer 1* and downloaded some content from iTunes, and put this onto my iPhone.

I have just authorised *computer 2*, can I transfer the data on my iPhone to *computer 2* or do I need to re-download everything?

It seems a bit of a waste having to re-download everything (a couple of gigabytes) when all of the content is already sitting right there on my iPhone.

I'm not trying to do anything dodgy, just trying to transfer some purchased apps/music from a non-jailbroken iPhone to a properly authorised computer, why does Apple make this so difficult?

This is my first apple device so I am new to the whole apple ecosystem, can somebody help me carry out this simple task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer purchases from your device to your computer.

1. Assure that you are signed into the AppleStore on the Computer
2. With the device plugged in via USB, Context-click (right-click) on the device and select "Transfer Purchases".

For more information and guided steps, please refer to this [AppleSupport Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1848)

Answer (score -1):

[Phone to PC](http://www.macroplant.com/phonetopc/) (or [Phone to Mac](http://www.macroplant.com/phonetomac/)) is some shareware that can be used for this, although the trial should be sufficient for your one time use need